# What is tricritical point？

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, material-science, physical-chemistry

Critical point is the transition temperature of a second order phase transition. But what does tricritical point mean? [WIki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricritical_point#cite_note-1) says that a tricritical point is a point in the phase diagram of a system at which three-phase coexistence terminates. But in [this](http://iopscience.iop.org/0301-0015/7/5/002)
 paper, it seems that the meaning of tricrital is different from Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction between the explanation of the tricritical point in the Wikipedia article and the usage of the term in the paper. In the latter, they use a model which consists of several components and exhibits phase transitions. They identify a tricritical point which fits the definition in the Wikipedia article.